# Memory filling when writing int vs uint16_t

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I have been looking through some code and I saw an interesting thing : at some point there is a line

```
pTable[i] = ((int *)val)[i]; // case 1
```

`pTable` is a `uint16_t` pointer and val is a `void` pointer; so I thought to change it to

```
pTable[i] = ((uint16_t *)val)[i]; // case 2
```

and spotted some differences in the output. So I start to debut it and see that the memory is getting arranged differently. Supposing that the data in the void pointer is something like `val[0] = 0x1234` and `val[1] = 0x5678`

- in the first case (case 1), the memory dump shows `addr 56781234`
- while in the second one (case 2) the memory dump shows `addr 00001234 00005678`

The code is a huge, not mine and I cannot put here, but it's a parser (it reads values form a file). What arrives in that void pointer may be `int` or `float` values (in my case, they were `int`).

I suppose it's something about interpreting the pointer data, but I cannot explain it myself, can someone explain it to me ? Thanks

Comment: If `val` points to the first element in an array of `int`, then your change violates the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: It's not assigned pointers but copying the values pointer to by them.  And the `uint16_t*` cast is the wrong type for `val` breaking the strict aliasing rule. As you say `pTable` is a pointer, so `pTable[i]` is the value pointed to ie a `uint16_t`

Comment: none of this makes any sense. `pTable` being an `uint16_t` pointer...

Comment: that's true, anda good question : why using `uint16_t` for int or float values ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` is probably 32-bit on your system while `uint16_t` is 16-bit.

This means that you'll access 32 bits of information at the address of `val[i]` in the first case and just 16 in the second case.

The place in the memory will also change since the `[]` operator is converted to this `*(val + i)` depending on the type of `val`. 
In other words, `((int *)val)[i];` is not at the same address as `((uint16_t *)val)[i];` unless `i` is 0;

The 'i' times `sizeof(val[0])` will determine the offset of the address of `val`.

Comment: doh... I see, if I convert the void to uint16 and the void points to int, I'll get the 00001234 because there are 2 uint16 values that represent the 32 bts int... Why didn't I see it ?! Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

Let's split the line `pTable[i] = ((int *)val)[i];` into pieces so that it is easier to understand:

```
void* val = something;             // val points to an object of some type.
uint16_t* pTable = something_else; // ptable points to a uint16_t object

int* intPtr = (int *)val; // We assume that val points to an int object.

int value = intPtr[i];    // Furthermore, we assume that the pointed int
                          // object is within an array of int objects.
                          // This expression gets the value of an int
                          // object that is i'th sibling element after
                          // the one pointed by val.

uint16_t converted = value; // This step is an implicit conversion
                            // in the original line.

pTable[i] = converted; // we assume that pTable also points to an
                       // element of an array and assign the i'th 
                       // successor of element pointed by pTable
```

So, if you change the cast from `(int*)` to `(uint16_t*)`, then you will be making an assumption that `val` points to an array of `uint16_t`. Clearly this is contradictory to the assumption that `val` points to an array of `int`.

Therefore if we assume that the original program was correct, then `val` indeed does point to an array of `int`. Therefore reading such value using a pointer to `uint16_t` will have undefined behaviour because that violates pointer aliasing rules.